# Tensorflow GPU Not detected : Centos

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I used to multi-gpu system in tensorflow.

however, from someday, the following code used CPU only.

```
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
```

Moreover, the return of physical device check function is empty

```
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

The return of nvidia-smi correctly show as following picture
[image]

Environment
NVIDIA_SMI: 418.87.00

Driver ver: 418.87.00

CUDA ver: 10.1

Tensorflow: 2.4.1

CuDNN:
[image]

How do I handle this issue?

Comment: Any system update? You may want to check and reinstall your GPU drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow 2.4 is compatible with **cudnn v8.0** and **cuda 11**.

So, upgrade cuddn and cuda.

If you are not using Anaconda, update the system paths and ensure they aren't any previous version.

e.g.,

`/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc --version`

Conda install:

```
# conda update --force conda ## if needed
# conda update conda ## if needed
conda activate <env>
conda install cudatoolkit
conda install -c anaconda cudnn
conda list cuda
conda list cudnn
```

Here is a script for manual install / you'll probably need even if using conda:

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/libnvinfer7_7.1.3-1+cuda11.0_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libnvinfer7_7.1.3-1+cuda11.0_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update

# Install development and runtime libraries (~4GB)
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends \
    cuda-11-0 \
    libcudnn8=8.0.4.30-1+cuda11.0  \
    libcudnn8-dev=8.0.4.30-1+cuda11.0


# Install TensorRT. Requires that libcudnn8 is installed above.
sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libnvinfer7=7.1.3-1+cuda11.0 \
    libnvinfer-dev=7.1.3-1+cuda11.0 \
    libnvinfer-plugin7=7.1.3-1+cuda11.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I know my TensorFlow version is not compatible with other support software from your comment. I downgrade TensorFlow version, and I solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed anything in eco system.

I would suggest you to install cuda 11 and cudnn 8.0 with tensorflow 2.4.0 and above.

Then give it a try. Hope your problem will be resolved.